# How to manipulate Play Framework WS response from java controller

Tags: java, playframework

In Latest Play JAVA (v 2.6) I am trying to fetch 3rd party restful api and process the response for further calculation in the controller. As the response type is a CompletionStage I am unable to convert it to usable JSON string from the response.
What I have tried,

```
final WSResponse r = (WSResponse) ws.url(domainUrl).setRequestTimeout(5000).get();
final JsonNode result = r.asJson();
```

But no help.
I also tried to fetch using java HttpURLConnection but there is no help either as the request is stopping for ssl skipping error, which only can be solved from play configuration.

Advance thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a synchronous WS call with Play Framework 2.2 (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545751/how-to-make-a-synchronous-ws-call-with-play-framework-2-2-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use plain Jackson to parse the body String:

```
final WSResponse r = ...;
Json.mapper().readValue(r, Type.class)
```